# How to determine what version TLS security protocol is register in OpenLdap

Tags: ssl, ldap, tls1.2, openldap, phpldapadmin

I am using the openLDAP. How do I determine what type of TLS version (TLSv1.0/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2) is using in LDAP? or which configuration file it is mentioned the TLS version?

Comment: It is in `slapd.conf` unless your OpenLDAP installation is using online configuration. Documented and off topic.

Comment: In slapd.conf  it is mentioned like - 
TLSCertificateFile    /usr/local/etc/openldap/ssl/cert.crt
TLSCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/openldap/ssl/cert.key
TLSCACertificateFile  /usr/local/etc/openldap/ssl/cert.crt

but did not found any specific TLS version. Then how to know that what type of TLS version (TLSv1.0/TLSv1.1/TLSv1.2) is using.
Please suggest me

Comment: Please do not post additional details in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: What about `TLSCipherSuite <cipher-suite-spec>` ? [@rtfm](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/tls.html#TLS%20Configuration). This relates to [openssl ciphers](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ciphers.1ssl).